# Disappearing Declarations, Adding Kie artifacts to a KieFileSystem

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

We are using KieFileSystem to dynamically manage Drools rules.  When I have a new rule I add it to the KieServices using KieFileSystem but I am overwriting my rules, not appending them.  As soon as I insert another rule the declarations I created in previous rules are no longer there.

- I modeled my code after this test [IncrementalCompilationTest.java](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/IncrementalCompilationTest.java)
- Simple example [KieFileSystemExample.java](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/main/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExample.java)
- Drools reference [4.2.2.4. Defining a KieModule
  programmatically](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR4/drools-docs/html/KIEChapter.html)

There must be a way to append these rules or there wouldn't be this way to change them?  The effect I am looking for can be achieved using the technique identified in [AddRemoveRulesTest.java](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/6.3.x/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/AddRemoveRulesTest.java).

```
KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
builder.add( ResourceFactory.newReaderResource( new StringReader( ruleBuilder.getRule() ) ), ResourceType.DRL);
if(builder.hasErrors()){
    _log.error( builder.getErrors().toString() );
    return;
}

//This is where the magic happens.  How equivalent with versioned deployable artifacts?  
base.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
```

If I am following IncrementalCompilationTest correctly, it seems to me that I will need to find a way to retrieve the existing rules and append them to the new jar with the new rule, in the manner of AddRemoveRuleTest.  I would prefer not going back to the database to pick up the existing rules. How?

If I am moving forward with this more awkward, yet maven compliant, method I need to figure out which is a better way to dynamically add rules to a session?  As far as I can tell, we use the add versioned Kie artifacts as maven practice, and the AddRemoveRulesTest method does not use that practice. See [drools-6-add-rules-to-a-running-kiesession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205945/drools-6-add-rules-to-a-running-kiesession)

Comment: The integration tests you are referencing here and also in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055637/kiefilesystem-vs-knowledgebuilder-adding-rules-to-a-running-kiesession  are tests and not really meant as examples for implementing Drools applications. Note that the imports include packages below org.kie.internal, all of which are not included in the *stable* part of the API, and not included in the Javadoc set that comes with the Drools installations. You advance into uncharted territory, danger ahead. The general advice is not to base apps on that code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and consideration of this question laune.  I deleted the other question so that we don't have the same comments in two places.  I'm still wondering if there is an answer.  As far as the practice goes there are plenty of people using dynamic rule building, I didn't just wake up and decide I'm going to build an implementation using internal libraries, this technique was recommended by heavy hitters on the org.drools board from RedHat.  Uncharted is fine, all these libraries were brought forward in the big code reorg.

Comment: In short, modifying a rule set at the DRL level is a CM activity which should be handled with CM tools. Rebuilding after such a modification is a build step best done again with the full (new) set. I don't know how switching to a new rule base and a new session is handled automatically by Drools but I would rather not rely on a process that may or may not be in accordance with the requirements of an app. If you find a doc with a commitment that a certain procedure does so-and-so, and you like it: by all means. Otherwise: take care.